# IIS login challenge for ASP.Net application

Tags: .net, authentication, iis

I have a legacy app that has a form based authentication. I need to set up a dev environment and I want to have a challenge authentication so that the site is only viewed by the dev team.

When I added basic authentication to the iis it works but it sets the Context.Request.IsAuthenticated property as true, the problem is that the same context variables are used by both authentication methods making them unreliable. Is there a way to separate this variables or any other way of showing a challenge login without interfering with the application (no code changes).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Windows Authentication and give only the development team permission to access the application folder.